# is there any example of Adobe Air application published on Mac App Store

Tags: air, adobe, app-store, appstore-approval

Since version 3 of AIR it's possibile to package application with "Captive Runtime" this means that the app doesn't require any other runtime. That was the limitation that blocked Air apps from being accepted in the Mac App Store in the past. With this solution i think that's possible to have your air app published but i can't find any example that proves this theory.

I'd like to confirm this before starting a new project that targets the Mac App Store.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Machinarium](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/machinarium/id423984210?mt=12) apparently is an AIR application published to the Mac App Store – according to [this article](http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2011/12/flash-player-11-1-and-air-3-1-update-for-android-4-0.html) on the Adobe blog.