# How to publish an Adobe AIR client in App Store (Mac OSX)?

Tags: air, app-store

How to publish an Adobe AIR client in App Store (Mac OSX)? (and I'm talking about a desktop client, not an iOS app)

Comment: possible duplicate of [is there any example of Adobe Air application published on Mac App Store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655934/is-there-any-example-of-adobe-air-application-published-on-mac-app-store)

Answer (score 0):

In russian http://www.pvsm.ru/adobe/26331
( + in the end there are some other links)